# What's the preferred way to start gem server?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I tried to start the gem server using the `server` command, ruby displayed the following message, saying the command is deprecated. However, it doesn't specify the command I should use.

```
➜  ~ ruby --version
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin20]

➜  ~ gem -v
3.2.19

➜  ~ gem server
WARNING:  server command is deprecated. It will be removed in Rubygems 4.
Server started at http://[::]:8808
Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8808
```

The [documentation](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-server) for the `server` doesn't say anything about being deprecated, either.

What's the new command I should be using to read the documentation of a ruby gem?

Comment: I would choose one of the servers mentioned on [Rubygems: Run Your Own Gem Server](https://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/).

Comment: Thanks, do you know the reason the `server` command would be deprecated? It does seem to be doing what it's supposed to do, as far as I understand.

Comment: I do not know why they made the decision to deprecate the `server` command. But IMHO running a server is very different from the usual use-case of `gem` and therefore it totally makes sense to have a dedicated app running a server instead of having this bundled with `gem` itself. Separation of concerns. And obviously, there are already better alternatives to the server that is included in `gem`.

Comment: A [quick google search](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/3868) yields: *the original reason for deprecating it was "we don't have bandwidth to address security issues on it"*. And as @spickermann says, more robust solutions exist elsewhere.